# how to loop all data on JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, while-loop

Hi I tried Looping my  `json_encode()` to get all data that are related based on my query
the script is working fine but not the looping part

here's what I have so far:

```
$con3 = new PDO("mysql:host=". db_host .";dbname=db", db_username , db_password);
$con3->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$con4 = new PDO("mysql:host=". db_host .";dbname=chat_db", db_username , db_password);
$con4->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :rid LIMIT 1";
$stmt6=$con4->prepare($sql5);
$stmt6->bindValue( 'rid',$_GET['rid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt6->execute();
    foreach($stmt6->fetchAll()as $res)
        {
            $usern = $res['username'];
            $user_lvl = $res['ulvl'];
        }

$comb = $usern . $_GET['name'];


  $sql6="SELECT msgid FROM thread WHERE combination1=:msgids OR combination2=:submsgids";
  $msg_id = $con4->prepare($sql6);
  $msg_id->bindParam(':msgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $msg_id->bindParam(':submsgids', $comb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $msg_id->execute();
  $msgd = $msg_id->fetchColumn();
  $tbpre = $msgd;
    $sql7 = "SELECT   message_content, username , message_time, recipient FROM ".$tbpre."chat_conversation WHERE msgid=:chat";

    $stmt7=$con3->prepare($sql7);
    $stmt7->bindValue( 'chat', $msgd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt7->execute();



  $message_query = $stmt7;


if(count($message_query) > 0) {
    while($message_array = $stmt7->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo json_encode($message_array);
    }
}
```

It only returns one data from my database..

this is my javascript for retrieving from my php side:

```
        function AjaxRetrieve()
        {
          var rid = document.getElementById('trg').value,
    data = {chat: uid, rid: rid, name: user};

$.get('includes/getChat.php', data, function (result) {
    var res = $([]);

    $.each(result[0], function(key, value) {
        res = res.add($('<div />', {text : value}));
    });

    $("#clog").html(res);

}, 'json');
        }
```

Comment: & that data must be the last one?

Comment: $json_string += json_encode($message_array);

Comment: @DeepakMane this is not the right way

Comment: yes $json_string_array[]= ($message_array); and last line will be  echo json_encode($json_string_array)

Comment: @DeepakMane what you gave didnt display anything.. why is that?

Comment: i don't think you need while loop

`$message_array = $stmt7->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
echo json_encode($message_array)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just keep overwriting $json_string with each loop iteration.

What you want to do is save your DB data to array then encode.

```
$array = array();
if(count($message_query) > 0) {
    while($message_array = $stmt7->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $array[] = $message_array;   
    }
}
$json_string = json_encode($array);
echo $json_string;
```

It also appears that in your AJAX success handler function, you are not properly iterating the array.

Notice here that you only call `$.each()` on the first array element of the returned result set:

```
$.each(result[0], function(key, value) {
    res = res.add($('<div />', {text : value}));
});
```

I would think you would want to iterate the entire result set like this:

```
$.each(result, function(rowKey, row) {
    // row is single row of result set from database
    // rowKey is numerical index of the row in the result set
    // rowKey is probably not useful here
    // You can just append new div to #clog with
    // whatever content from row which you desire
    // for example, this would insert message_content value
    // in child div to #clog
    $("#clog").append('<div>' + row.message_content + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: Hi I've tried this code the output was `[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]`

any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: @user256009 Can you show your usage?  That looks like something you would get if you tried to `echo` an object, not what you would get if you JSON encoded an array and then echoed the JSON string.

Comment: I have viewed the response of your script and it displayed a set all of my data from database on an array format.. but how come its displaying `[object Object]` on my page =(

Comment: @user256009 It looks like where are dealing with `result` in your AJAX success handler, you are only calling `$.each()` on the first array item that is returned - `result[0]` I would think you would want to iterate the entire result set.  I will update answer with some additional commentary.

Comment: your right master @Mike Brant it gave me all the message content... but does this mean that I have to add more `$("#clog").append('<div>' + row.message_content + '</div>');` for me to display other data based from my needs? for example I also need to add the username and time/date from my json result.. do I need to add 2 more of those?

Comment: @user256009 You can get all the different column values you want for each row while iterating that row in the loop. How you build the HTML really depends on how you are trying to display this info.

Comment: I have made it worked by just like this `$("#clog").append('<p><h4>'+ row.username +':</h4>' + row.message_content );` but why does it only display what was written before and not the actual data that was being stored

Comment: @user256009 Why did it not work before?  Because you were iterating over individual members properties of the first record previously.  You could put an `console.log(key, value);` just inside your `each()` loop in your original code to get a better idea of why this was incorrect.

Comment: on `console.log` it displays what was just inserted but why does it not work when I try to append it...?

Comment: @user256009 I guess I am not understanding your question.  A few comments ago, I thought you said you were getting it to work using `append()`. I thought you were asking why it wasn't working originally.  I am not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Your code snippet worked as what I have asked/posted for but there are few things that I want to clear out. One why this code displays only data that was not inserted freshly to my database thus if my database is empty and I try to insert a data.. At first it wont display anything because it reads my database as empty the 2nd I type a new word to be stored to my DB and submitted it displays the earlier data that was stored.. =(

Comment: @user256009 I have no idea.  You should ask separate question with pertinent code, as your current question doesn't show any relation between inserts and selects to be able to have any understanding of the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: yeah it was my mistake.. which is why I have accepted your answer because it was the answer I'm looking for the my posted question.. I just realized that what I'm asking is a different question.. Thanks for the help Master @Mike Brant

Answer (score 1):

Please use [`->rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to count rows:

```
$json = array();

if($message_query->rowCount() > 0) {
    while($message_array = $stmt7->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json[] = $message_array;
    }
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

You should use an array to store your message_arrays, so that you're not just replacing the same variable over and over.

Comment: is `->num_rows` usable on PDO? Because I think the reason why your code snippet isnt showing any result on my end is the compatibility of `->num_rows` I'm not sure though =)

Comment: Sorry, I have changed my code. Also, if you're getting [object Object], is this from the Dev tools or is that the direct source?

Comment: yes I've tried it its working and yes the output that I'm getting  from the direct source is `[object Object]`

Comment: Please post what you are getting for `print_r($json)`, instead of `echo json_encode($json)`. Perhaps the data is already not what you might expect.

Comment: here is the result from firebug
`Array([0] => Array
([0] => Array
([message_content] => asdafgga
 [username] => ab
 [message_time] => 2014-04-03 14:50:03
 [recipient] => cd)` i've cuted the result cause its too long but this is definitely printing the whole data

Comment: I've only seen `[object Object]` from firebug/dev tools. I hate to ask again, but what does your clientside look like? Is that your exact PHP code?

Comment: I've edited my post incase I missed something I have already included your snippet on my post is that ok?
thats my whole code for the retrieving of data from database

Answer (score 1):

Try This.....

```
$i=0;
$fet=mysql_query('select * from tbl1 WHERE tbl1.id='20');
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($fet,MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
$json[$i]['date']=$row['time'];
$i++;
} 
echo json_encode($json);
```